# How do LCD monitor contrast settings work?

Tags: display, lcd, contrast

Most monitors have settings for brightness and contrast. I understand the brightness setting, it only (mostly) controls the brightness of the LCD backlight.
How does the contrast setting work, exactly, though?
Does it affect the backlight? Does it affect the panel?
Does it cause blacks to be more / less black? If so, why would you want anything but the darkest black?
Does it cause whites to be more / less white / bright? If so, why not lower the backlight brightness?

Comment: Please read [Adjusting Brightness and Contrast on LCD](http://www.galacticmag.com/monitor/adjusting-brightness-and-contrast_o1.html) and then [edit] your question to be more specific if necessary. At the moment it is too broad.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've read the link, it explains how to set the brightness and contrast, but it doesn't explain how the contrast setting works / is implemented in a technical way. Not sure what you'd like me to edit.

Comment: I asked in another stack and got IMO a good answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694821/brightness-contrast-controls-what-they-do-on-lcd-displays